# How to best coerce a list of numpy arrays into a pandas dataframe column?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a list (posterior_list) of 18,000 `numpy arrays` with length 82,868.  I have a dataframe (y_test) with shape `(82,868, 1)`.  The arrays are posterior predicted values.  I would like to append each array inside that list as a column onto the dataframe (y_test) with the end result having shape `(82868, 18001)`.

I tried the following:

```
for arr in posterior_list:
    x_test.append(arr)
```

That resulted in the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-144-a200df62319d> in <module>
      1 for arr in posterior:
----> 2     y_test.append(arr)

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\stan_env\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in append(self, other, ignore_index, verify_integrity, sort)
   6690         return concat(to_concat, ignore_index=ignore_index,
   6691                       verify_integrity=verify_integrity,
-> 6692                       sort=sort)
   6693 
   6694     def join(self, other, on=None, how='left', lsuffix='', rsuffix='',

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\stan_env\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\concat.py in concat(objs, axis, join, join_axes, ignore_index, keys, levels, names, verify_integrity, sort, copy)
    226                        keys=keys, levels=levels, names=names,
    227                        verify_integrity=verify_integrity,
--> 228                        copy=copy, sort=sort)
    229     return op.get_result()
    230 

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\stan_env\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\concat.py in __init__(self, objs, axis, join, join_axes, keys, levels, names, ignore_index, verify_integrity, copy, sort)
    287                        ' only pd.Series, pd.DataFrame, and pd.Panel'
    288                        ' (deprecated) objs are valid'.format(type(obj)))
--> 289                 raise TypeError(msg)
    290 
    291             # consolidate

TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type "<class 'numpy.ndarray'>"; only pd.Series, pd.DataFrame, and pd.Panel (deprecated) objs are valid
```

So I tried the following:

```
for arr in posterior:
    arr = pd.Series(arr)
    y_test.append(arr, ignore_index=True)
```

`MemoryError: Unable to allocate array with shape (82877, 82868) and data type float64`

Can anyone advise on the best way to loop through my list, and append each array as a column onto my dataframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
y_test.join(pd.DataFrame(posterior_list,columns=y_test.index).T)
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you mean?

```
for i, arr in enumerate(posterior_list):

    y_test["list_{}".format(i)] = pd.Series(arr)
```